# Tagable Image In Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a Targeted Email system for a client. They want to be able to send poster style emails and then make area's of the image clickable in the recipients browser. I am sure that this can be done using tech like PHP mailer; but does anyone know of a way/library to tag the image's and allow the user to make them clickable via a browser interface?

Cheers 
Shaun

Comment: Are you talking about **map** tag (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) to make some areas on image clickable.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the suggestion I will check it out. Not to fused what method I use as I am coming at this from a blank!

Comment: Please don't recommend W3Schools, it has many issues. I would also be surprised if there was widespread support for image maps in email clients that support HTML formatted email.